# Blur all list items except selected one

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a list of items. When you click one item, it expands. I want to blur all list items except expanded one.

```
<li href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="task in taskVm.tasksdata | orderBy: 'NAME' | filter: search | statusFilter: taskVm.statusArray">
  <div class="row" ng-click="task.isCollapsed = !task.isCollapsed">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <lable>[[::task.NAME]] </lable>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
      <lable ng-class="taskVm.getStateClass(task.STATUS)">[[::task.STATUS]] </lable>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <i ng-click="taskVm.openAlternativeTask(task)" class="fa fa-question-circle-o fa-stack-1x pull-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div uib-collapse="task.isCollapsed">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <lable>[[::task.MESSAGE]] </lable>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row" ng-hide="task.M.length ===0">
        <hr>
        <label>Alternatives</label>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="alternatives-list list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="alternative in task.M" ng-click="showAlternative(alternative.ID, alternative.SETNUMBER); taskVm.setSelected(alternative.SETNUMBER)" ng-class="{selected: alternative.SETNUMBER === taskVm.idSelectedVote}">[[alternative.SETNAME]]</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is my list

Comment: Can you show me your jsfiddle / full code ? Check my answer that will give you a way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will apply the test class to all the div except first into the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-class="{'test': !$first}"></div>
```

See the working example, That will help you to do the rest of things in your code. When you click some item, It will change the class for that item only.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Item 1' },
    { name: 'Item 2' },
    { name: 'Item 3' },
    { name: 'Item 4' },
    { name: 'Item 5' }
    ];
    $scope.selected = 0;
    $scope.select= function(index) {
       $scope.selected = index; 
    };
});
```

```css
.blur
{
  color:red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <a ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{blur: $index == selected}">{{item.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```